# How do I optimize my download speed with aMule?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, p2p, emule

I have several questions regarding [aMule](http://www.amule.org/) (which also could apply to [eMule](http://www.emule-project.net/)).

1. How do I optimize my download speed? I do not understand exactly how it all works.
2. If I am uploading data, will my downloads receive a higher priority?
3. Does the serverlist/server I am connected to have any impact on my download speed?
4. What do the columns in the following screen capture mean? Specifically:

   - What does **8/9+23** mean in the *Source* column?
   - What does **294/300(1)** mean in the *Source* column?
   - What does **QR:608(0)** mean in the *Priority*?
   - ***What do I do for getting fast download speed as much as I can get?***

[image: aMule downloads]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question**: "Is serverlist important? Does it cause my download-speed?"
**Answer**: The serverlist has no practical impact on your download speed. Servers are used for searching by filename.

**Question**: "What does 8/9+23 mean in the Source column?"
**Answer**: You are connected to 8 out of 9 sources. 23 other sources "asked for another file."

**Question**: "What does 294/300(1) mean in the Source column?"
**Answer**: You are connected to 294 out of 300 sources. 1 source has actually sent you chunks of the file.

According to the [aMule FAQ](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/FAQ_aMule):

> **What do all those numbers in the sources column in the transfers window mean?**
> The sources format is XX/YY + ZZ (WW) where
>
> - XX stands for the number of sources available (the number of sources found that you can download from)
> - YY stands for the number of sources found (the total number of sources found)
> - ZZ stands for the number of "Asked for another file" sources
> - WW stands for the number of sources from whom you are currently downloading some chunk of that file.

**Question**: "What does QR:608(0) mean in the Priority?"
**Answer**: This is your queue position for that particular source.

**Question**: "What do I do for getting fast download speed as much as I can get?"
**Answer**: The ED2K network's strongest feature is probably its reliability. The best you can really do is make sure you have a High ID (allow incoming connections to the client through your firewall and NAT). If you try to change aMule to query more often, or act abusively to the network, you will probably just be auto-banned by many of your sources. You might find the following articles helpful:

- [Why is aMule slow?](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/AMule_is_slow)
- [How to get High ID](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/Get_HighID)

**Question**: "If I provide higher upload-speed or more valuable files to other people, can I get benefit?(My download speed)"
**Answer**: I don't think so, but I'm not entirely sure. ED2K used to implement a credit based system, but this was somewhat controversial and theoretically exploitable. I don't know if it's still around in any form.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. Could you give me the answers for my first two qurious.

Comment: @Benjamin done and done.